# Using SMO to create and set Database permissions?

Tags: sql-server-2005, permissions, authentication, smo

Is there a way to create new logins and set database permissions on a `SQL Server 2005` using `C#` and `SMO`?

If so, how? If not, what is the best way of doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Login class and call the Create method. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms208073(SQL.90).aspx) for more details.